# Repopulate Laravel Input::old() on Form::select

Tags: php, laravel

I can't manage to repopulate a Select field input after a query, using Laravel 4:

```
// Route
Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@getPosts');


// BlogController
public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = Post::where('category_id', Input::get('category'))->paginate(25);

    $categories = Category::lists('title', 'id');

    return View::make('blog', compact('categories', 'posts'));
}

// Blog view    
{{ Form::open('method' => 'get', 'id' => 'form-search') }}

    {{ Form::select('category', $categories, Input::old('category')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I managed to make it work this way, but it's not the best practice

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="1" {{ (Input::get('category') == 1) ? 'selected="selected"' : null }}>Category 1</option>
    <option value="2" {{ (Input::get('category') == 2) ? 'selected="selected"' : null }}>Category 2</option>
    <option value="3" {{ (Input::get('category') == 3) ? 'selected="selected"' : null }}>Category 3</option>
</select>
```

I think the `Input::old('category')` doesn't work because it is a GET request, am I right? Is there any workarounds?

Update : I finally made it work using `Input::get()` instead of `Input::old()` :

```
{{ Form::select('category', $categories, Input::get('category')) }}
```

Comment: The 2nd argument to `Input::old()` is a default value in the event that old is empty. `Input::old('category', null);` for instance.

Comment: I guess so, but I'm 100% sure that my input is not null, since my posts listing works well, and my uri looks like `/?category=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $category_id = Input::get('category');

    $posts = Post::where('category_id', $category_id)->paginate(25);

    $categories = Category::lists('title', 'id');

    return View::make('blog', compact('categories', 'posts', 'category_id'));
}

// Blog view    
{{ Form::open('method' => 'get', 'id' => 'form-search') }}

    {{ Form::select('category', $categories, $category_id) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: That worked well, and then I tried simply using `Input::get()` instead of `Input::old()` and it worked too! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're not even retrieving the old input, you will need to pass it to the view. You can do that in one of two ways, the easiest and best to understand is to just specify that you want to pass input.

```
return View::make('blog', compact('categories', 'posts'))->withInput();
```

Also, you don't need the markup in your HTML. Laravel will do this for you if you just give it the value of the old Input. It works very well.